# Why isn't _mm_div_epi64/_mm_div_epu64 defined?

Tags: c++, simd

I've noticed that _`mm_div_epi64/_mm_div_epu64` isn't defined in the headers for `simd` intrinsics and I don't get why it wouldn't. If it was multiplication it would make sense since **64bit * 64bit = 128bi**t, which would overflow but **64bit / 64bit = 64bit**.

Unless there's some unforeseen issue with 64bit division for xmm registers.

Note: I am using **Visual Studio 2017**

Answer (score 0):

Which header are you looking in?  According to the [Intel Intrinsics Guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide), both of those instructions are defined in "immintrin.h".

Comment: I am including immintrin.h through intrin.h. Also I did a text search through all the files included recursively to find the signature. No luck.

Comment: [`_mm_div_epi64`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm_div_epi64&expand=2040,2040,2040) *et al* are [Intel SMVL](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523792) functions, not intrinsics - you need to be using the Intel ICC compiler to take advantage of these.